# How Can I Read Excel Files In Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**I have pyspark3.4.0 installed and i'm trying to read an excel file using spark in python.**

i can read csv files without any error but i'm unable to read excel files

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark_df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
                    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
                    .option("header", "true") \
                    .load("c.xlsx")
spark_df.show()
```

this code gives error:

```
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: com.crealytics.spark.excel. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.dataSourceNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:738)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:647)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:697)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:186)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:633)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:633)
        at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:633)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: Did you add the package to Spark?

Comment: After downloading and adding spark-excel jar by  --jars /home/centos/spark-excel_2.12-0.12.3.jar for pyspark ClassNotFoundException error is solved.

Comment: how can i get the package( i'm using ubuntu system)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the spark-excel package to spark like this :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("local") \
.appName("read_excel") \
.config("spark.jars.packages", "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.12.2") \
.getOrCreate()
```

Then continue with the same code.

Comment: it gives: 
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class

Comment: @DoraXplora wanted to comment here, but my code is too big for a comment, hence added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see, this might happen due to version mismatch. For the workaround, you may load the file into pandas dataframe and convert it to spark dataframe in the next step like this :

```
import pandas as pd

# Read to pandas dataframe
pd_df = pd.read_excel('dummy_data.xlsx', header=0)

# Below 3 functions will ensure spark dataframe is getting the right datatypes of columns
def pandas_to_spark(spark, pandas_df):
    columns = list(pandas_df.columns)
    types = list(pandas_df.dtypes)
    struct_list = []
    for column, typo in zip(columns, types):
        struct_list.append(define_structure(column, typo))
    p_schema = StructType(struct_list)
    return spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df, p_schema)

def define_structure(string, format_type):
    try:
        typo = equivalent_type(format_type)
    except:
        typo = StringType()
    return StructField(string, typo)

def equivalent_type(f):
    # Detecting the base datatype using if-else
    if f == 'datetime64[ns]':
        return DateType()
    elif f == 'int64':
        return LongType()
    elif f == 'int32':
        return IntegerType()
    elif f == 'float64':
        return FloatType()
    else:
        return StringType()

# Call the pandas_to_spark function
spark_df = pandas_to_spark(spark, pd_df)

# Display the spark dataframe content
spark_df.show(5, False)

+---+------+----------+
|ID |NAME  |DEPARTMENT|
+---+------+----------+
|1  |Joshua|HR        |
|2  |Steven|IT        |
|3  |Cyril |Ops       |
|4  |Mark  |HR        |
|5  |James |Admin     |
+---+------+----------+
```